# CircleCI Dynamic Config / Config breakdown

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, circleci

Does anyone know if it's possible to breakdown the config file for circleci into smaller files where each job, command, workflow, etc, is in it's own specific file/subdirectory, and if so, how would you approach this?

I've been looking around and even attempted myself to build a python script to build a config from all these yaml files, but with no luck due to reference variable names not existing in these various files so pyyaml library won't load them.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have this folder structure

```
configs/
  dependencies.yml
  commands/
    command_1.yml
    command_2.yml
  jobs/
    job_1.yml
    job_2.yml
  workflows/
    workflow_1.yml
    workflow_2.yml
```

Where `dependencies.yml` contains a breakdown of what each workflow requires in terms of what is used in each step > job > command. And this file would be hand written.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

- Split your config.yml in a structure defined in [Packing a config](https://circleci.com/docs/how-to-use-the-circleci-local-cli#packing-a-config)
- Use [dynamic configuration](https://circleci.com/docs/dynamic-config) where you fist generate the config from step 1 and the  call the generated config file from them main file

---

Example original config.yml to split:

```
version: 2
orbs:
  sonarcloud: sonarsource/sonarcloud@1.0.3

jobs
  my-job:
    docker:
        - image: cimg/latest
    steps:
        - checkout
        - run: make

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      -my-job
```

---

Create following layout in a new folder called config (run `tree`):

```
.
├── config.yml
└── config
    ├── @orbs.yml
    ├── jobs
    │   └──my-job.yml
    └── @workflows.yml
```

---

@orbs.yml contains

```
version: 2
orbs:
  sonarcloud: sonarsource/sonarcloud@1.0.3
```

---

@workflows.yml contains

```
workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      -my-job
```

---

my-job.yml contains

```
docker:
  - image: cimg/latest
steps:
  - checkout
  - run: make
```

---

And the main config.yml should look like:

```
version: 2.1
setup: true
orbs:
  continuation: circleci/continuation@0.3.1

jobs:
  generate-and-run-circleci:
    docker:
      - image: 'circleci/circleci-cli:latest'
    steps:
      - circleci-cli/install
      - checkout
      - run:
          command : |
            cd .circleci
            circleci config pack config > generated.yml
      - continuation/continue:
          configuration_path: .circleci/generated.yml

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - generate-and-run-circleci
```